# Ruby on rails "no route matches" when trying to use a separate controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, networking, network-programming, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I'm currently trying to map my building's network with a RoR implementation. I have a good floor plan set up, and I've created the switch objects for it as well. Eventually, the switches will have many jacks, and each jack will map one-to-one with a room number.

Currently everything is working perfectly through the floors and switches until I try to show the switch individually. I'm trying to do this by using the show method in a separate controller. Originally the floor controller was in charge, but now I want the switch controller to be.

Here is my partial switch code (apps/views/switch/_switch.html.erb):

```
<p>
  <%= switch.title %>

  <%= link_to 'show', :controller => "switches", :action => 'show'  %>

  <%= link_to 'Destroy', [switch.floor, switch],
               :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
               :method => :delete %>
</p>
```

Here is my show method (apps/controllers/switches_controller.rb):

```
...
  def show
    @floor = Floor.find(params[:floor_id])
    @switch = @floor.switches.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @switch }
    end
  end
...
```

When I do not tag the switch controller in the partial, whenever I click show the link acts as a link back to the same page...basically just a refresh. When I do tag the switch controller I get the ' No route matches [GET] "/assets" ' error.

I've tried MULTIPLE different syntaxes and nothing has worked. If anyone can help me out I will be very thankful!!

Please let me know if it's necessary to post more of my code and I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run **'rake routes**' command to list all available routing options and recommend you to use url/path rather than specifying controller and actions for individual links.

I assume that you have setup nested route for floor and switch, then to obtain this URL i.e

```
/floors/:floor_id/switches/:id/show
```

you can use

`<%= link_to "Switch", floor_switch_path(switch.floor, switch) %>`

Answer (score 0):

'Show' method used to display particular element. Particular switch in your case. So you need to send :id to your controller, like this

```
link_to "Switch", :controller => "switches", :action => "show", :id => switch
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this worked as well. I had the first two statements, but never tried the switch id, and now that makes perfect sense. Thank you!